# Swagger UI: basic auth for swagger file

Tags: javascript, swagger, basic-authentication, swagger-ui

My Question is how can I add a authorization header into my index hmtl before getting the swagger file.
I´m getting the swagger file from a http url which uses basic auth. So I need to provide user and password before calling the Service.
So now I need to know where I add the header.

```html
$(function () {
      var url = window.location.search.match(/[?]url=([^&]+)/);
      if (url && url.length > 1) {
        url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
      } else {
        url = "test.json";
      }
      

      hljs.configure({
        highlightSizeThreshold: 5000
      });

      // Pre load translate...
      if(window.SwaggerTranslator) {
        window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
      }
      window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
        url: url,
        dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
        supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'],
        onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
          if(typeof initOAuth == "function") {
            initOAuth({
              clientId: "your-client-id",
              clientSecret: "your-client-secret-if-required",
              realm: "your-realms",
              appName: "your-app-name",
              scopeSeparator: ",",
              additionalQueryStringParams: {}
            });
          }

          if(window.SwaggerTranslator) {
            window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
          }
        },
        onFailure: function(data) {
          log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
        },
        docExpansion: "none",
        jsonEditor: false,
        defaultModelRendering: 'schema',
        showRequestHeaders: false
      });

      window.swaggerUi.load();

      function log() {
        if ('console' in window) {
          console.log.apply(console, arguments);
        }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If the spec is on another domain, then the browser will do a pre-flight OPTIONS request to determine CORS.

Unfortunately this is done automatically by the browser so there is no way to add the Authorization header to this request. The only solution is to configure the server hosting the spec to not require Authorization for OPTIONS requests.